# External makefile in Atmel Studio won't build. Windows error 0xc0000142

Tags: makefile, avr

I downloaded bitcloud, the atmel zigbee stack and I am trying to compile one of the default applications, ZLLDemo.

It is located currently at:

```
C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\BitCloud_MEGARF_3_1_0\Applications\ZLLDemo\atmelStudio_projects\ATmega256RFR2.cproj
```

Everytime I try to compile the application I get a windows message screen for "mkdir.exe" error 0xc0000142. In the Output screen I see the line "make: *** [directories] Error -1073741502"

This same error and error code occurs later in the build process for cp.exe if I manually make the folders myself.

I have tried the following things to fix the error:

- Change folder and contents to different owners, everyone having full
  privileges
- run make command manually from a command prompt window as admin
- clean solution before retrying
- all other examples files
- ran directly from C: as "C:\BitCloud_MEGARF_3_1_0\Applications\ZLLDemo\atmelStudio_projects\ATmega256RFR2.cproj" - as per general suggestion for the windows error I tried

  - "sfc /scannow" in case mkdir had somehow been corrupted
  - Changed AppInitDLLs Reg key to 0 to load all DLLs at start of application
  - Disabled Internet security

Does this have a general fix or is there perhaps something else at work here? General compilations work, its just external ones. My friend did the same and it seems to work just fine for him.

Windows 8.1

Atmel Studio 6.2

Comment: I've got an idea I saw that the latest version of Visual Studio which it's based on has some path size limit. Maybe try putting the project at `c:\test` or something similar and reduce some of the directory name lengths and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avrfreaks had a solution that I finally found [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/windows-81-compilation-error).

Their solution is to download an old version of the msys file for winavr. Which means that their is something more than likely wrong with the latest version of winavr for windows 8.1

sebastor wrote:

```
I found solution.

Copy this file:

http://www.madwizard.org/download/electronics/msys-1.0-vista64.zip

to utils\bin directory (WinAVR)
```